# Reasonable way to have different versions of None?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, nonetype

Working in Python3.

Say you have a million beetles, and your task is to catalogue the size of their spots. So you will make a table, where each row is a beetle and the number in the row represent the size of spots;

```
 [[.3, 1.2, 0.5],
  [.6, .7],
  [1.4, .9, .5, .7],
  [.2, .3, .1, .7, .1]]
```

Also, you decide to store this in a numpy array, for which you pad the lists with None (numpy will convert this to np.nan).

```
 [[.3, 1.2, 0.5, None, None],
  [.6, .7, None, None, None],
  [1.4, .9, .5, .7, None],
  [.2, .3, .1, .7, .1]]
```

But there is a problem, values represented as None can be None for one of 3 reasons;

1. The beetle dosn't have many spots; that quantity does not exist.
2. The beetle won't stay still and you can't measure the spot.
3. You haven't got round to measuring that beetle yet, so the value is unassigned.

My problem doesn't actually involve beetles, but the principles are the same.
I want 3 different None values so I can keep these missing value causes distinct. My current solution is to use a value so large that it is physically improbable, but this is not a very safe solution.

**Assume you cannot use negative numbers - in reality the quantity I am measuring could be negative.**

The data is big and read speed is important.

Edit; comments rightly point out that saying speed is important without saying what operations is a bit meaningless. Principle component analysis is probably going to be used for variable decorrilation, Euclidean distance squared calculations for a clustering algorithm (but the data is sparse in that variable) possibly some interpolation. Eventually a recursive neural network, but that will come from a library so I will just have to but the data into an input form. So maybe nothing worse than linear algebra, it should all fit in the RAM if I am careful I think.

What is a good strategy?

Comment: If you want different values, don't use `None`. Use some other type. This is not what `None` is for.

Comment: @khelwood perhaps I should open the question; I need a better strategy for dealing with the missing value problem. It may not involve None anywhere.

Comment: If you use numpy array why using `np.nan`, `np.inf` and `-np.inf` is not  a solution?

Comment: Maybe add a column with number of spots? That shows how many of the other columns have a valid value, and there can be special values like -1 and -2 for the other cases.

Comment: Would [Masked Arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html#what-is-a-masked-array) make sense for your problem?  They're one way of representing invalid/missing data.  I don't know how much of a performance impact there would be though.

Comment: @GrzegorzBokota That is brilliant. I love it. My values can never be infinity so those are quite safe.

Comment: [Create an `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#creating-an-enum) whose values are the different flavors of `None`.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I did not know about these and they look like they are designed for this. Thank you. Would you consider expanding this to an answer?

Comment: @martineau that sounds promising, how will numpy see these objects?

Comment: You can make the values negative integers to keep `numpy` happy.

Comment: @martineau I ought to have chosen a better analogy because negative values are not safe in this problem.

Comment: `Enum` values can be anything you like—so there may be a better `numpy`-compatible choice.

Comment: @martineau `enum` will necessitate dtype=object arrays, so it will impact performance a lot.

Comment: These are all nice answers, but to give a really GOOD answer we must know what kind of manipulation/operations you will do on these arrays. Otherwise, what is the speed that you refer to?

Comment: If speed is important then stick with numeric dtypes and values.  `object` dtype will hurt performance.

Comment: @LiranFunaro Your right, I intentionally avoid talking about the specifics of the problem because firstly it's a bit verbose, and secondly I don't have a fixed method yet. The problem is particle jet tagging for jets in boosted geometries. The solution will be some data whitening, variable decoration followed by a DNN or an RNN. So most of the operations that need to move fast will be in the variable decorilation and data whitening, probably transforming to PCA is the largest operation, but some uses of psudo rapidity in rotating vectors can also be expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was suggested to create three different `object` instances for each of your case.

Since your want those objects to have the properties of `NaN`, you may try creating three different `NaN` instances.

```
NOT_APPLICABLE = float("nan")
NOT_MEASURED = float("nan")
UNKNOWN = float("nan")
```

This is at the limit of being a hack, so use at your own risk, but I don't believe any Python implementation optimizes `NaN` to always reuse the same object. You can nonetheless add a sentinel condition to check that before running.

```
if NOT_APPLICABLE is NOT_MEASURED or NOT_MEASURED is UNKNOWN or UNKNOWN is NOT_APPLICABLE :
    raise ValueError # or try something else
```

If this works this has the advantage of allowing you to compare the `NaN` id to check its meaning.

```
row = [1.0, 2.4, UNKNOWN]

...

if value is UNKNOWN:
    ...
```

Meanwhile, it preserves any optimization `numpy` may do with its array.

*Disclosure: this is a hacky suggestion, I am eager to hear from others about this.*

Comment: Accepting this one because the sentinel improves it so much.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to go would be with strings: 'not counted', 'unknown' and 'N/A'. However if you want to process quickly in numpy, arrays with mixed numbers/objects are not your friend.

My suggestion would be to add several arrays of the same shape as your data, consisting of 0 and 1. So the array `missing` = 1 where spot is missing else 0, and so on, same with array `not_measured`, etc..

Then you can use NaNs everywhere, and later mask your data with, say, `np.where(missing == 1)` to easily find the specific NaNs you need.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want an object that is not any known value, and is also not `None`, just make a new object:

```
NOT_APPLICABLE = object()
NOT_MEASURED = object()
UNKNOWN = object()
```

Now you can just use those values exactly like you would use `None`:

```
[1.4, .9, .5, .7, UNKNOWN]

...

if value is UNKNOWN:
    # do something
```

etc.

If you need a value that can be represented as a `float` (e.g. in a `numpy` array), you can create a NaN value with "extra" data encoded in the mantissa. It may not be *safe* to do so, however, because there is no guarantee that those bits are preserved through various operations on the values.

Comment: But that's going to confuse Numpy, I think. It can translate None to NaN and keep it an array of floats, but if there are random Python objects there that won't work.

Comment: I honestly don't know what `numpy` does in that case. I believe it can store arbitrary objects in an array, it just switches to a different kind of array. But I don't know how else you would do this sort of thing.

Comment: OP did say it was a numpy array (should probably have tagged it though). I think also performance is a significant issue here, which is why s/he doesn't simply use strings (which are the same as objects in terms of numpy speed)

Comment: @DanielPryden yeah, sorry I buried it a bit. The reason for padding with None is to convert to a numpy array. This is done to improve the speed of various subsequent operations. This seems like a good solution though, I might have to figure out how to do it in a way compatible with numpy.

Comment: This will require a dtype=object array, which will remove the speed advantages of numpy.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution (disclaimer: HACK!) that avoids speed bumps such as object dtype or separate masks:

There appears to be quite a bit of "dead space" around the fp representation of `nan`:

```
>>> nan_as_int = np.array(np.nan).view(int)[()]
>>> nan_as_int
9221120237041090560

>>> custom_nan = np.arange(nan_as_int, nan_as_int+10).view(float)
>>> custom_nan
array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan])
```

We have created ten distinct `nan`s. Please note that this is different from creating multiple instances using `float("nan")`. Such instances will all map to the same value in numpy and hence be indiscriminable once put in a non object array.

Even though our ten `nan`s have distinct representations, at the float level they are difficult to tell apart (because per definition `nan != nan` even for unique `nan`). So we need a little helper:

```
>>> def which_nan(a):
...     some_nan = np.isnan(a)
...     return np.where(some_nan, np.subtract(a.view(int), nan_as_int, where=some_nan), -1)
```

Example:

```
>>> exmpl = np.array([0.1, 1.2, custom_nan[3], custom_nan[0]])
>>> exmpl
array([0.1, 1.2, nan, nan])
>>> which_nan(exmpl)
array([-1, -1,  3,  0], dtype=int64)
```

Perhaps surprisingly, this appears to survive at least some basic numpy operations:

```
>>> which_nan(np.sin(exmpl))
array([-1, -1,  3,  0], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the comment below question I ask why not use `np.inf`, `-np.inf` and `np.nan` and author response that this is what he need.

So I add post, because people more often look on responses, not comments.

Comment: While I think mine is a better answer in the general case, this is probably better for this specific case, +1

Comment: I'm not sure. The author write "The data is big and read speed is important." So adding svereal 0,1 arrays is not a good idea. 

I thin add one array with different marks (1,2,3,...) is better than several arrays.

Comment: Yes, as I said yours is better for this specific case, but there could be a case where `np.inf` could also be an actual value, then you'd need another solution

Comment: This provides enough flexibility for my needs, and it probably won't break with future implementations. For someone who needed more versions @PaulPanzer solution would probably be the solution, but in my ignorance I would probably say it is not as safe.